# Echo URL on 404 error page

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I want a 404 page to write `The page at "/fake/path/index.php" could not be found`, but it
always writes `The page at "/404/index.php" could not be found`. (/404/index.php is the error 
document).  How can I access the path that was being accessed (/fake/path/index.php) instead? (I am using .htaccess ErrorDocument 404)

`.htaccess:`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
```

`/404/index.php:`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>404 Error</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <h1 id="page_title" style="text-align: center;">404 Error - Not Found</h1>
      <span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">
        The page at "<a href="$dir"><?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?></a>" could not be found.  Possible causes of this are:
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mind showing us your `.htaccess` and `/404/index.php` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're querying `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` which **will** return `/404/index.php` as that is the file name.

What you want is to use `REQUEST_URI`:

```
<span style="font-size: 14px; color: black;">
        The page at "<a href="$dir"><?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?></a>" could not be found.  Possible causes of this are:
      </span>
```

Comment: @user3238291 perfectly alright :-) You should always read the php manual - [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). (*makes things so much easier ;-)*)